# Unsubdivide curve

Tags: bezier-curves, grease-pencil, annotation

I have converted annotation tool to a curve. But the vertices are too dense. Is there a way to unsubdivide it? Like for example by selecting every other vertex?

Or is there a straight way to draw a curve right onto a mesh surface?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Try a simplify modifier on the grease pencil objet. If you want to simplify the curve enter edit mode, select all vertices and then do checker diselect, that will leave the selection to every other vertex.

Answer (score 3):

When in edit mode press Right Click > Decimate curve, Then in the bottom left corner click on the foldout (Or press F9) and set the decimation ratio.

This will keep the original shape more precisely than deleting every other vertex.

Answer (score 2):

For part a) You can selected every other vertex by the select checker deselect method. In edit mode select all verticies that you want to "unsubdivide", then through the Select menu, choose Checker Deselect (Note this has . Be cautious of selecting the end points of your curve.

However I am sure there may be better ways?